# VS Code Omnisharp.MsBuild.Projectmanager can not load assembly System.Numerics.Vectors 4.1.3.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, csproj, omnisharp

I'm having a problem with opening a newly created blazorwasm project. Omnisharp will not start correctly. This is the output:

```
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager Failed to load project file 'c:\VS.NET2010\CoreApp\Server\CoreApp.Server.csproj'.
c:\VS.NET2010\CoreApp\Server\CoreApp.Server.csproj(1,1)
System.IO.FileLoadException: Kan bestand of assembly System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a of een van de afhankelijkheden hiervan niet laden. De manifestdefinitie van de gevonden assembly komt niet overeen met de assembly-verwijzing. (Uitzondering van HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Bestandsnaam: System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
   bij System.SpanHelpers.IndexOf(Char& searchSpace, Char value, Int32 length)
   bij Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Expander`2.Function`1.ExtractPropertyFunction(String expressionFunction, IElementLocation elementLocation, Object propertyValue, UsedUninitializedProperties usedUnInitializedProperties, IFileSystem fileSystem)
   bij Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Expander`2.PropertyExpander`1.ExpandPropertyBody(String propertyBody, Object propertyValue, IPropertyProvider`1 properties, ExpanderOptions options, IElementLocation elementLocation, UsedUninitializedProperties usedUninitializedProperties, IFileSystem fileSystem)
   bij Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Expander`2.PropertyExpander`1.ExpandPropertiesLeaveTypedAndEscaped(String expression, IPropertyProvider`1 properties, ExpanderOptions options, IElementLocation elementLocation, UsedUninitializedProperties usedUninitializedProperties, IFileSystem fileSystem)
   bij Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Expander`2.PropertyExpander`1.ExpandPropertiesLeaveEscaped(String expression, IPropertyProvider`1 properties, ExpanderOptions options, IElementLocation elementLocation, UsedUninitializedProperties usedUninitializedProperties, IFileSystem fileSystem)
   bij Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Expander`2.ExpandIntoStringLeaveEscaped(String expression, ExpanderOptions options, IElementLocation elementLocation)
   bij Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ExpandPropertyUnescaped(ToolsetPropertyDefinition property, Expander`2 expander)
   bij Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.EvaluateAndSetProperty(ToolsetPropertyDefinition property, PropertyDictionary`1 properties, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties, PropertyDictionary`1 initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties, String& toolsPath, String& binPath, Expander`2& expander)
   bij Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ReadToolset(ToolsetPropertyDefinition toolsVersion, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties, PropertyDictionary`1 initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties)
   bij Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ReadEachToolset(Dictionary`2 toolsets, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties, PropertyDictionary`1 initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties)
   bij Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ReadToolsets(Dictionary`2 toolsets, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties, PropertyDictionary`1 initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties, String& msBuildOverrideTasksPath, String& defaultOverrideToolsVersion)
   bij Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetReader.ReadAllToolsets(Dictionary`2 toolsets, ToolsetRegistryReader registryReader, ToolsetConfigurationReader configurationReader, PropertyDictionary`1 environmentProperties, PropertyDictionary`1 globalProperties, ToolsetDefinitionLocations locations)
   bij Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.InitializeToolsetCollection(ToolsetRegistryReader registryReader, ToolsetConfigurationReader configReader)
   bij Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection..ctor(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, IEnumerable`1 loggers, IEnumerable`1 remoteLoggers, ToolsetDefinitionLocations toolsetDefinitionLocations, Int32 maxNodeCount, Boolean onlyLogCriticalEvents, Boolean loadProjectsReadOnly)
   bij Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection..ctor(IDictionary`2 globalProperties)
   bij OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore(String filePath) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:regel 123
   bij OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject(String filePath) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:regel 72
   bij OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load(String filePath, ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, ProjectLoader loader, Guid sessionId, IDotNetCliService dotNetCli) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectFile\ProjectFileInfo.cs:regel 113
   bij OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<LoadProject>b__0() in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:regel 302
   bij OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject(String projectFilePath, Func`1 loader) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:regel 313

WRSCH: registratie van assembly-bindingen is uitgeschakeld.
Als u assembly-bindingsfouten wilt registreren, stelt u de registerwaarde [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) in op 1.
Opmerking: er is een prestatiestraf gekoppeld aan de registratie van assembly-bindingsfouten.
Als u deze functie wilt uitschakelen, verwijdert u de registerwaarde [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

This is the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="3.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Client\CoreApp.Client.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\CoreApp.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I have no clue why I get this error. Due to this I am not able to use IntelliSense in this project.
A colleague of mine does not have this problem. He can create a similar project with the command:
`dotnet new blazorwasm -o CoreApp --hosted`

On his PC the project opens just fine without any OmniSharp warning.

I do not ave a clue why I get this error on my PC.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Had the same issue with a colleague today. In my Environment (VS Code, .NET Core and Omnisharp Extension set up a long time ago, but updated to the most recent version) everything works fine. On his PC (set up today) the error shows up for every C# project. It also happens for most simple console apps created with 'dotnet new console'. Therefore I guess it is a bug with the current version of Omnisharp.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried all kinds of things, I also think this is a bug in the current version 1.22.1 (which according to the Changelog I see in VS Code is Not Yet Released :p). Hopefully they will release another version soon. Any other suggestions are still welcome. I'm still searching for a solution, will post it if I find one. Please let me know if your colleague finds a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the included MSBuild in the C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp) VS Code Extension is not able to correctly locate the specific 4.1.3.0 version of System.Numerics.Vectors on the system.

The best solution is to just add the correct version of the DLL in

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics.Vectors\v4.0_4.1.3.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

Another solution is to install .NET Core SDK 3.1.301 which contains that version of the System.Numerics.Vectors assembly and then copy

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\tools\net472\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
```

to

```
%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1\.omnisharp\1.35.3\.msbuild\Current\Bin
```

This issue will probably be resolved in a later version of the C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp) VS Code Extension

Comment: For the first part here, I just made a copy of the entire 4.1.4 directory and called it 4.1.3.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to `runtime` section of `MSBuild.exe.config` necessary version that installed in GAC.

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.4.0" newVersion="4.1.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
```

To check version installed on your host:

`gacutil.exe -l System.Numerics.Vectors`

Usually gacutil located in SDK `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\`

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried your solution, but I found a better one (imho) thanks to your answer: I just added the correct version of the System.Numerics.Vectors.dll in my GAC in the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics.Vectors\v4.0_4.1.3.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a" directory.

Comment: yes. Adding necessary assembly to GAC was my first solution. But I refused it because I do not know why 4.1.3 version of  the System.Numerics.Vectors.dll does not exist in GAC. Dependencies of Microsoft packages and distributives are very difficult and changing manually some system settings can make parts of OS windows fail.